# The larger scope of autofocus zxing in android

Tags: android, android-camera, zxing

I am deving an app with zxing,but in some condition,I want to Cap QRCODE in a long distance.May we set a larger scope when the camera autofocus?or zoom out the camera when init.If it,what should I do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Autofocus modes already attempt to focus at the maximum range of the camera if necessary. You could modify the code to always select "infinity" focus mode, if available. Zoom does not generally help, as it is only digital zoom, not optical. Zoom can actually hurt in some cases due to scaling artifacts.

Comment: Thank you,I agree with you,but my boss think ,zoom out the camera can imporve the recognition rate of the zxing core.I insist he made a mistake.

Comment: @Sean Owen: Thank you for providing this wonderful library. I am using this library in Android version 2.3.0 (got this number from pom.xml). In some situation, we might require auto flash druing scan process. My question is if I need to implement auto flash ? Or is it already implemented in this version ?